# Getting error on the lift state up between the 2 react components need & tried various method passing between the 2 components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

Tried to fix the issue in various methods and ways but it's not fixing. I am not able to know why it's getting an error I don't understand the exact issue in the code. Could anyone help with the solution?
[image]

[image]

ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-gagarin-k54vf

```
<TextField
              id="productTitle"
              name="title"
              label="Product Title"
              ariaLabel="Product Title"
              value={values.title}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              error={!!errors.title}
              helperText={errors.title ? errors.title : ""}
              showLabelHelperText={false}
              labelHidden={true}
              inputProps={{ maxLength: 60 }}
            />


    
    
    
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={10}>
                <Typography color="textSecondary" className={classes.newproducts}>
                {values.title || "New Product"}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
```

Hi how can do the react lift state up between this 2 component the first-1 text field is one component(Form.js) and the Grid part is in another component file(app.js)
if i try to change the text field it needs to updated replaing the new Product with the entered text-field

u can use this approach as reference for codesand box https://codesandbox.io/s/lifting-state-up-example-1-hooks-forked-ygfbh

Comment: Can you please show where and how you define the `values` variable?

Comment: @Nico Graf check the  codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-gagarin-k54vf

Comment: Please show a [mcve] in your question. You can include a link to the code sandbox as well, but your question should show enough code for us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: In addition, [edit] your question to tell us what line causes the error.

Comment: @prohith I cannot find your code from the question here in the Code Sandbox. Also, the code does not compile. There's another error shown! Please reduce the code so we don't have to search ourselves and make it compile without errors. Then show us exactly which part is in question.

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your code

1. Missing Value
2. Using `<Link/>` outside `<Router/>`.

Fix 1 : User simple ternary operator when you are not sure

***/src/App.js:61***

`{values && values.title ? values.title : "New Product"}`

Fix 2 :

**Never use**
`<Link/>` outside `<Router>`

Updated Example :

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-pine-qym61?file=/src/App.js:1599-1654

Comment: Hi i had updated the code https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-dawn-bv9lx